# How to convert PHP Array with requirement

Tags: php, arrays

is there any way to convert the below array to normal array in php ?

```
[["2"],["2","3","4"],["8","9"],["7","4"]]


["2","3","4","8","9","7"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flatten the 2d array using something like `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);`. Then call [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to eliminate the duplicates, and [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) if necessary.

```
$newArray = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $oldArray));
sort($newArray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WlsbR)